# How do you clarify the period for which a debt has been accruing?

Tags: phrase-usage

You haven't made due payments for, say, one month, how do you say it? 'One month's debt'? 'Debt for one month'?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed one mortgage (or loan) payment, commonly expressed as being **one month behind** with your mortgage/loan/rent.

https://www.quora.com/Im-struggling-with-mortgage-payment-one-month-behind-and-may-not-be-able-to-pay-for-3-months-to-come-Is-there-anything-I-can-do-to-have-a-break-until-I-sort-my-finances-out

Comment: I want to involve the word 'debt'

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure, but the phrasing of your question makes it sound like you are asking about a debt (or portion of a debt) where you are behind in payments. This is called **in arrears** or an **arrearage**.

Arrears: the state of being behind in the discharge of obligations —usually used in plural

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arrears

Comment: "One month arrears" then?